# Using ckeditor functionality for styling small pieces of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I am the current sole developer of a content management system (FreeToastHost) used to produce free websites for over 10,000+ Toastmasters public speaking clubs around the world.  CKEditor is one of the key open source plugins we use to make this system possible.  Our users are generally very low tech, and the system is designed to make creating a website as simple as possible for them.  In addition to the full-blown text areas used with CKEditor for page content authoring, I have a number of text inputs in our configuration tool forms that allow our users to do some styling of text "snippets" used in various places in the system via entry of basic BBCode.  For example, the club identification text used in the masthead (called the "banner" for our users benefit) supports the entry of BBCode:
[image: Entry of BBCode for "Banner" text]

---

I tend to think that requiring our users to enter BBCode may seem too technical to some of them, and I am looking for a way to employ the CKeditor functionality that we already are using for these small, possibly styled, text snippets.  What would be ideal is a basic simple floating styling toolbar that shows up when the user clicks in the input.  As these are currently inputs, I am thinking I may have to convert them to content-editable divs or text areas to use with CKEditor (would prefer not to convert), and create a new config for the pop-up toolbar that is used just for these controls.  Has anyone done anything like this before with CKEditor?  What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [inline mode of CKEditor](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html).

A simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/jhvtz6pb/

Load the CKEditor script and CSS styles:

```
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<link href="http://sdk.ckeditor.com/theme/css/sdk-inline.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, just add a `contenteditable="true"` attribute to the elements that you want to edit.

Comment: Ok, but my understanding is with the inline editor, I have to use divs or text areas for the container, with preference for divs.  As I want to be able retrieve a defaultValue to check for unsaved changes on form exits, I think that pretty much means I have to swap out my various text inputs for textarea's (since they have a defaultValue property).  Is that a fair assessment?